# Refresh NSView content when the view is displayed with MAAttachedWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

Im my application, I display a NSView when a user click on an icon in the systemstatusbar.
This NSView is displayed with MAAttachedWindow.

My question is : how to refresh the NSView content when the attachedWindow is displayed (makeKeyandorderFront)

I've tried to refresh the content in the awakeFromNib method,but it works only once.

Could anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I've found:

I've added a observer in my view:
I've set the object to [selft window] to listen the NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification notification of the MAAttachedwindow.

> -(void)awakeFromNib
>
> {
>
> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeKey:) name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:[self window]];
>
> }
>
> -(void) windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)note
>
> {
>
> // Do refresh here
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

The reason -awakeFromNib only works once is presumably because you're only loading the assembly from the xib once and keeping it around.

Presumably whatever action actually shows your view in the MAAttachedWindow instance is the ideal place to "refresh" it before display, ie your own call to -makeKeyAndOrderFront:.

So: What have you tried?

Comment: I found a solution this morning : I added an observer in my view to the windowDidBecomeKey notification from the MAAttachedwindow. add peform the refresh in the selector. (I've tried this solution before ask my question but due to another bug, this was not working and causing application hang)